# How to select another row right after deleting row in tableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am deleting row and want to get next behavior:

1. If I am deleting row that was selected, I need to get another row selected automatically.
2. And also if I have an additional trouble, when I am perform deleting, target row that is going to be deleted selecting automatically, I don't need it to be selected as I want to only delete it.

The main question is 1 for now.

I understand that maybe row: 0 does not exists anymore but t's not a point now, I just simplified code to make it more comfortable to discuss the point. I tried performBatchUpdates, and tried to move selectRow(at:section:) to completion closure as well, row selection not works too.

selectRow works perfectly after insertRows function, so I am confused.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .middle)

    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but `beginUpdates / endUpdates` is pointless in this case. It has no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question, find this solution:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```

Pass indexPath while deleting a  row and after endUpdates, you just need to set the same indexPath as SelectedRow.

Comment: how come passing same indexpath to deleteRows and selectRow will work? After deleting will that indexpath exist?.. Before selectRow reload TableView.

Comment: Suppose you have 5 rows index from 0 to 4, now you deleted 3rd index row. So after deleting 3rd row now, you have a total 4 rows index from 0 to 3. Now after deleted cell at index 3rd would be next one that was on the 4th index.

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, I need to select any row after deleting target. Anyway, your solution not works. For example in range from 0 to 4 I delete index 3, and then just need to select index 0. Not work anyway as you suggested.

Comment: Then you can select 0th index row instead of this line: tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)

Comment: You might want it to select "any" row, but your code should use a way of picking the selected row. Like the row above the deleted one... I do not think you meant  "random indexPath of remaining rows"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found solution for the 1st question (just thought maybe such function can exist and typed **didrowat**, and xcode suggested this **didEndEditingRowAt** :)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
}
```

Now first part of question is answered, I've inserted selection there.

The second question is still opened, how to make selected row keeping still selected while I am removing another row. I don't need selected row to deselect at all if I am removing another one.